# My turtle cracked his plastron

Tags: health, turtles, first-aid

We took the turtle out of his tank for a second. He ran off the bench so quickly that we couldn't catch him falling. He fell on the floor, cracking his plastron. I'm trying to take him to the vet, but they're not open yet.

I put him back into his tank, I'm not too sure what to do for him until we can get to the vet.

[image: Turtles cracked chest]

Comment: Hopefully you have been to the vet by now, if you can share the answer the vet gave you it may help someone else in the future.  - You can answer your own question.

Comment: Hope this little guy is doing ok..

Comment: May i know its appetitle?If it still have the appetitle to eat should be no problem.

Comment: I feel bad for that poor turtle, I hope he is OK! They haven't updated this to tell us yet.

Answer (score 3):

Is there blood? Do you see any notable difference in the way he walks? or the way he is acting?

The picture is blurry but the break doesn't look as bad as it could have been. In simplified terms, a turtle's shell serves the same purpose as a bug's exoskeleton. If the break is complete the vet may wire it shut or they may even use super glue. This is still what most would consider an emergency, so if you have the cash then please take him in sooner rather than later. Monitor his behavior overnight. Note any changes and take him into the vet right when they open tomorrow.

If you notice any oddities in his behavior, then please take him into a 24 hour vet. Otherwise, I think he will be okay until the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Keep checking on him to make sure he doesn't make it worse or that it doesn't get worse on it's own. Get him to the vet ASAP or even search for a 24 hour animal hospital in your area. Watch him carefully to see if he is acting in pain and such. If so make sure the shell hasn't broken more. Hopefully you have gotten him to the vet by now. Best Wishes for your Turtle!